# How to invoke an XML RPC method with Python when the method name is only known at runtime?

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I've got some Python code below that invokes an XML RPC method:

```python
from xmlrpclib import ServerProxy

s = ServerProxy("http://localhost:8000")
s.SomeMethod('parameter')
```

However, what happens when the name of the method (`SomeMethod`) is only known at runtime? Is there any way to invoke a method when the name of the method is in a variable?

I've tried the following and none of them work:

```python
s['SomeMethod']('parameter')
s.__getattr__('SomeMethod')('parameter')
getattr(s, 'SomeMethod')('parameter')
```

All of them return:

```
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault -32601: 'Method not found'>
```

---

**Further edit:** this is starting to get really strange. When I use `s['SomeMethod']('parameter')`, the remote server reports that I tried to invoke the XML method `__getattr__`.

Comment: ISTM the `getattr` approach should work: I just verified it with a small test SimpleXMLRPCServer.  Are you sure that SomeMethod really exists?

Comment: That's **extremely weird**. I am positive it wasn't working a minute ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getattr` works as expected for me. 
It fails if I try to get a `repr` of the returned value, as the ServerProxy class does not expose a "repr" method. Thus, if from the interactive prompt, I type just:

```
>>> getattr(proxy, "is_even")
Traceback (most recent call last):
(...)

xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: '<type \'exceptions.Exception\'>:method "is_even.__repr__" is not supported'>
```

But I can do this:

```
>>> a = getattr(proxy, "is_even")
>>> a(5)
False
>>>
```

(The server-side snipped used is the one from Python's cmlrpc documentation:
http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html )